# Multifocal IOLs under EASA

Tags: medical, easa

I have a question about passing EASA Class 1 medical having done an eye surgery with Multifocal IOLs installment. Was not an issue with FAA Class 1 medical as both eyes have 20/20 vision , near intermediate and distant. Have a letter from head FAA doctor that states that I am eligible for class 1 FAA medical with no limitations!
EASA says that IOLs “should” be monofocal not shall or must.
I would appreciate a good feedback or a source that would give me an answer or if someone had an experience with this issue.
Thanks in advance